# Is it possible to slow down system clock?

Tags: windows-7, javascript, time, date-time

I'm playing a game that is using JavaScript to get system time, and I need the best time in the game I can get, I tried Cheat Engine but, as I said game uses JavaScript, so it is of no help to me. I tried SleederXP, but it didn't help either. I have Ubuntu installed so I tried libfaketime but I didn't know how to use it on Firefox. So is there a way to slow system time on Windows, for example that 5seconds real time is shown as 1sec?

Answer (score 0):

There is a program (which I've never used called) [ASpeeder](http://www.cs504.com/index0.htm). I've no idea how it works, if it works, or if it's an ancient scam site. Try at your own risk

It is payware ($20). Take a look, and be sure to virus-check the download before you install.

A Speeder 2008.4 Features (from the website):

Features:

```
• Change the speed of desktop games or online games
• Control application speed and windows speed
• Easy to use, just drag the track bar or press hotkey
• From 1/32 times speed to 32 times system speed
• From 1/256 times speed to 256 times Windows speed
• The speed setting is locked automatically
• Offer three kinds of methods to change speed
```

Source from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/50820/is-there-any-software-or-hardware-which-lets-you-stop-slow-down-speed-up-or-ev)

Comment: It doesn't work on Win 7, I tried it.

Comment: @MinaSimic I'm sorry to hear. In that case check out the source there are other answers on there that might be worth a look into